# Disposing EntityConnection disposes also DbConnection within?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, idisposable

in my project I am using one of the overloads for instantiating EntityConnection.

```
internal static EntityConnection GetEntityConnection(string name)
{

    metadataWorkspace = new MetadataWorkspace(...);

    var connection = new SqlConnection(GetConnection(name));
    connection.AccessToken = OptionalAccessToken(connection);
    if (connection.State != ConnectionState.Open)
    {
        connection.Open();
    }

    using (var ec = new EntityConnection(metadataWorkspace, connection))
    {
        return ec;
    }
}
```

I am wondering, when the `EntityConnection` instance gets disposed automatically thanks to the usage of `using` does also the open connection within get disposed?

Comment: @GertArnold wrong copy paste sorry, thanks for pointing it out! Edited it now

Comment: OK, so then you should remove the `using`. The receiving code should dispose the connection.

Comment: @GertArnold understood, and when the EntityConnection will be manually disposed from the receiveing code, does also the SqlConnection within get disposed automatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to your question lies in the reflecting of the `EntityConnection`. Look into that and see for yourself, if underlying connection gets disposed. Many objects do something like that

```
public void Dispose()
{
    // dispose underlying objects
    _privateMemeber.Dispose();
}
```

For example, there was such a bug in MySql .NET provider.

But the general rule should be, "if you have not created it, you don't dispose it". In your case, `using` should be used outside of `GetEntityConnection`

```
using (var ec = new GetEntityConnection(...))
```

After you research, if `EntityConnection` disposes underlying object, that should be enough.

Otherwise you need to create disposing hierarchy

```
using (var conn = new GetConnection(...))
using (var enConn = new GetEntityConnection(...))
{
   . . . .  .
}
```

Comment: When you say "reflecting" do you mean "decompiling"?

Comment: @CaiusJard yea. Remember, when most common decompiler was "Reflector". Now, I think "dotPeek" is good

Comment: ILSpy fan here, but I remember redgate

Comment: @T.S. I checked out the E.F. repo and saw indeed that the connection gets disposed in there. So I am safe! Thanks for the lesson and for the suggestion! :)